# Help regarding docker & Ardupilot Copter v4.3

Tags: ardupilot

Can anyone please help with the docker for SITL?

Once the docker run, I can not connect it from my host machine nither from QGroundControl.

Thanks

Not working

```
docker build . -t ardupilot
docker run --rm -it\
    -v $PWD:/ardupilot\
    ardupilot:latest bash
```